# How to set a default value for an AMP uninitialized variable?

Tags: amp-html

```
<input type="checkbox" [required]="(currentState == null) ? (true) : (false)">
```

amp-bind: Default value for [required] does not match first expression result (true). This can result in unexpected behavior after the next state change.

EDIT: Maybe some more context could help

```
<amp-state id="privacySettings">
      <script type="application/json">{                                   
           "general": {
               "mp": "required",
               "p1": false,
               "p5": false
           },
           "specific": {
               "mp": false,
               "p1": "required",
               "p5": "required",
               "ck": false
           }
       }
   </script>
</amp-state>
<div class="privacy">
    <div id="pmaindiv">
        <input on="tap:err_mess.hide" role="mainmandatoryprivacy" tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="main-privacy" id="pmain" class="pmain" value="1"  [required]=privacySettings[currentState].mp  [checked]=privacySettings[currentState].ck >
```

Every attempt to assign to [require](but it also stands for [checked] and, I guess, for other attributes) a value(statically or through a var) gets the bind-amp error.

```
<amp-state id="temp">
     <script type="application/json">
          {
           "var": "general"
            }
     </script>
</amp-state>

(...)  [required]="(currentState==null) ? privacySettings[temp.var].mp : privacySettings[currentState].mp" (...)
```

It passes validation and works fine if currentState is setted via 'on' attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you setting the `required` attribute as well as the `[required]` binding?

Try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       [required]="(currentState == null ? 'true' : 'false')" 
       required="true">
```

Separately, if a variable is not defined you can use this,

```
(myVar || 'defaultVal')
```

If `myVar` is not defined, then the value `defaultVal` will be used instead.

But the most correct way to set a default value is to use `<amp-state>` like this:

```
  <amp-state id="props">
    <script type="application/json">
      {
        "myVar": "blah"
      }
    </script>
  </amp-state>
```

Then you would use that variable by prefixing with the `id` you gave to the `amp-state` element like this:

```
props.myVar
```

EDIT: The following works for me

Note:
 
1. Setting `currentState` in the initial `amp-state` element
2. Default value for basic `required` attribute

```
<amp-state id="privacySettings">
    <script type="application/json">
    {   
      "currentState":"general",                              
      "general": {
        "mp": "required",
        "p1": false,
        "p5": false
      },
      "specific": {
        "mp": false,
        "p1": "required",
        "p5": "required",
        "ck": false
      }
     }
 </script>
</amp-state>
<div class="privacy">
    <div id="pmaindiv">
        <input role="mainmandatoryprivacy" tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="main-privacy" id="pmain" class="pmain" value="1"  
        required="required"
        [required]=privacySettings[privacySettings.currentState].mp
        >

  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT 2: The following should also work, when currentState has not been initialised:

```
<amp-state id="privacySettings">
    <script type="application/json">
    {                              
      "general": {
        "mp": "required",
        "p1": false,
        "p5": false
      },
      "specific": {
        "mp": false,
        "p1": "required",
        "p5": "required",
        "ck": false
      }
     }
 </script>
</amp-state>


<amp-state id="temp">
     <script type="application/json">
          {
           "var": "general"
            }
     </script>
</amp-state>

<div class="privacy">
    <div id="pmaindiv">
        <input role="mainmandatoryprivacy" tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="main-privacy" id="pmain" class="pmain" value="1"  
        required="required"
        [required]=(currentState==null?privacySettings[temp.var].mp:currentState) 
        >

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great. It seems the attribute ' required="required" ' is necessary.

Comment: @rodders , how would you change/update that default value?